# Spring-boot, by database platform custom property

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to have spring boot `init-sql` dynamic property by vendor or platform. Is this possible?

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.mysql-initSQL=mysql query
spring.datasource.tomcat.h2-initSQL=h2 query
```

I do know that is possible with other properties for example with flyway migrations:

```
flyway.locations=db/migration/{vendor}
```

or with sql initilization file

```
schema-${platform}.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the Spring Profiles.

Create 2 profiles. 
`1) H2 2) MySQL`

Create two init sql files in your class path `schema-h2.sql, schema-mysql.sql`

Add the `spring.datasource.platform` property to the profiles

```
In H2 Profile => "spring.datasource.platform = h2"
In MySQL Profile => "spring.datasource.platform = mysql"
```

This works as below.

When you application is started with h2 profile (spring.profile.active=h2) then the schema-h2.sql is picked for initialization.

When you application is started with mysql profile (spring.profile.active=h2) then the schema-mysql.sql is picked for initialization.

Comment: thanks for answer but this will required actually set the active environment and platform (2 new properties)  to automatically get a third one`init-sql`  in this case I will prefer to use init-sql per environment instead. My point if is possible to get without  a hardcoded property indicating database type.